# Bulk query in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

We have a database of 1 Million records, and we would like to query list of emails using UserID's.

What's the best way to do it in Elastic search. We don't want to loop individual UID and get respective email. If we can get all emails with one bulk search that would be great.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you should show how your current DB schema looks like and how you'd query it to achieve what you need. Also maybe for the benefit of others having similar needs, explain why you want to take this approach (performance, etc)

Comment: what is the schema of your ES document? does each document contain email and userid fields? By `database` do you mean elasticsearch?

Comment: Depending on the number of UIDs that you want emails for, it may be possible as a single query. Ideally you would want to do a filtered search. If you are using a pre 2.0 version of elasticsearch. There may be ways to speed this up depending on your schema, but these types of queries are typically problematic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
POST localhost:9200/users/user/_search?pretty=true
{
    "_source": "email",
    "query" : {
        "match" : { "userId" : "abc123" }
    }
}
```

or

```
POST localhost:9200/users/user/_search?pretty=true
{  
    "query" : {
            "match" : { "userId":"abc123" }
        },
        "fields": ["email"]
}
```

I recommend first one.

Comment: Note that you need to add the `_search` endpoint to your URLs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/search-multi-search.html) for this purpose:

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch/template -d '
{"index" : "logstash-2017.03.20"}
{"inline": {"query": {"match":  {"uid" : "E434C35-B080-403C-ADA9-2FD164CF70" }}}}
{"index" : "logstash-2017.03.20"}
{"inline": {"query": {"match":  {"uid" : "E1D65ED3-F3BE-42E8-AF2F-A4D4F843F7" }}}}
'
```

**Note**: each search command (pair index and query line) must be separated by a new line a also after last query a new line must be present. It might be safer to write query into a file e.g. `requests` and then use `--data-binary` flag:

```
curl -s -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch/template --data-binary "@requests"
```

You will obtain an array of `responses` for each query:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "took": 86,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 13.081283,
        "hits": [
          { ... }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "took": 82,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 13.081283,
        "hits": [
          { ... }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```